# Is the newly added 'My Card' that automatically shows up in IOS9 a reliable way to get a users phone number?

Tags: ios, ios9, addressbook

Am I correct that with a address book permission we should be able to pretty reliably get a users phone number if they have given address book permissions via the new  "My Card" contact that seems to be automatically added to your addressbook when you download IOS9?

I always wanted to do a find friends but i did not want to force users to type/verify their number....this seems to be a solid work around for ios9 users.

Answer (score 1):

I am currently dealing with the same issue but unfortunately it seems that this is not possible according to Apple.

"Presuming that you’re working on iOS, there’s no programmatic way to identify the ‘me’ card.  If you need to know, ask the user."
source: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/37564