# iOS Contacts framework: select "me" contact

Tags: ios, swift, contacts

In iOS's Settings -> Mail, Contacts, Calendar you can set "My Info". This brings up a list of contacts from which you can select yourself. Then, if you open the Contacts app, you can see a label "me" next to the contact you have selected before.

Using the Contacts API in iOS9, is it possible to look up the "me" contact programmatically? And if it's not set for whatever reason, is it possible to allow the user to set the "me" contact from my app?

EDIT:
Via [Rob's link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34113809/is-the-newly-added-my-card-that-automatically-shows-up-in-ios9-a-reliable-way), one gets to [Apple's forum](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/37564). An Apple Staff member's answer to this question is currently "ask the user".

Comment: It would appear not. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/34113809/1271826. While at first glance it seems like an glaring omission, in retrospect, it's a logical privacy protection that, were it not present, could easily be abused by developers. E.g. just because I want an app to be able to use my contacts so I can interact with contacts via the app, it doesn't mean I really want to give the app developer my home address, personal email address, etc.

Comment: Ah, thanks. I searched only for "me" card, so I didn't find that discussion. Case closed, for now, I suppose. :)