# How to find my own contact on iOS programmatically?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I know getting your own device's phone number has been a hot topic in the past, and I've seen some tricks to trying to find it.

In my application, I have already been granted CNContactStore permission, so is it possible to query for my own contact?  I noticed that in newer iOS versions the contact list will show my contact and number at the top of the contact list.  If a user has identified their own contact, is it possible for an application with contact permission to find that entry?

I've seen some hacks of searching the contacts for a name based on the iPhone name, etc, but I was hoping that an application with explicit permission should be able to be smarter about finding owner information.

Is this possible in iOS 9.1+?

Comment: [iOS contacts framework: select "me" contact](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38133363)

Comment: Thanks a lot, I wasn't able to find the questions for the "me" contact.

Comment: Glad I could help.